# How do I fetch all rows of a model with its relations?

Tags: bookshelf.js

I have the following models:

**role.js**

```
let bookshelf = require('../config/database');

var Role,
    Roles;

Role = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'roles',
    users: function() {
        return this.hasMany('User');
    }
});

Roles = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: Role
});

module.exports = {
    Role: bookshelf.model('Role', Role),
    Roles: bookshelf.collection('Roles', Roles)
};
```

**user.js**

```
let bookshelf = require('../config/database');

var User,
    Users;

User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    role: function() {
        return this.hasOne('Role');
    }
});

Users = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: User
});

module.exports = {
    User: bookshelf.model('User', User),
    Users: bookshelf.collection('Users', Users)
};
```

My database tables are like this:

user: id, name, username, role_id
role: id, description

I need to get all users with their roles (id and description), then I tried doing this:

```
User.where({})
            .fetch({withRelated: ['role']})
            .then(function(result) {
                res.json({data: result.toJSON()});
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.json({error: JSON.stringify(err)});
            });
```

But all I get is this:

```
{
    "error": "{}"
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer:

```js
User.forge()
            .fetchAll({withRelated: ['role']})
            .then(function(result) {
                if (result === null)
                    res.json({data: []});
                else
                    res.json({data: result.toJSON()});
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.json({error: err.message});
            });
```